# Is it possible to solve for y in this equation?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-polynomials

Is it possible to solve for $y$ in this equation? $$-y^{-x}+y-1=0$$ People have mentioned the use of the Lambert W function or other non-elementary functions, but I haven't been able to make use of them. I'd preferably like to find a closed form expression using elementary functions, but if that isn't possible any other equation with $y$ isolated is fine.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: there is no closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions (and I would not know how to solve it in term of some known special function either)

Comment: related answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257455/inverse-function-of-y-frac-lnx1-ln-x
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491579/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-equation-x-1-x-y-explicitly/4492364#4492364 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116276/what-is-fx-if-f-1x-frac-lnx1-ln-x?_gl=1*1hef901*_ga*NTExMTAxNjQ0LjE2NjY1NTA3MDE.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3MDAwNTcwMy4xMTQuMS4xNjcwMDA2NzMxLjAuMC4w

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. In fact, this is a trinomial equation. A closed form expression can be obtained using confluent Fox-Wright Function $\ _1\Psi_1^*(\zeta)$. [See here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3.pdf)

A linearly convergent series can be worked out for $x>0$ starting from [this MO link, here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial/418468#418468)

$$y = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nx+1}\cdot \binom{(nx+1)/(x+1)}{n}$$ where binomials must be expressed in terms of Gamma Function.

You can look at these previous answers in MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406250/transcendental-formulas-for-roots-of-polynomials/406340#406340) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406250/transcendental-formulas-for-roots-of-polynomials/406340#406340) as well.

Since Fox-Wright function is a special case of Fox-H function, you can work with the closed form solution using last versions of Wolfram's Mathematica that have implemented Fox-H. Some steps in this line are found in the former links.